# Divide into groups according to the specified attribute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I need to group the data in such a way that if the difference between the adjacent values from column a1 was equal to the same pre-specified value, then they belong to the same group. If the value between two adjacent elements is different, then all subsequent data belong to a different group. For example, I have such a data table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [5, 2],
    [100, 23],
    [101, -2],
    [303, 9],
    [304, 4],
    [709, 14],
    [710, 3],
    [711, 3],
    [988, 21]
]
columns = ['a1', 'a2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

If the difference between the elements of column a1 is equal to one, then they belong to the same group and the answer in this example will be the following:

```
[[0], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8]]
```

The output list stores indexes that correspond to rows from df.

It may also be useful that column a1 is ordered. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont quite understand the wanted output. Do you want it to bring the index, of the row whose previous value is equal to one? But them why, would you display 0. Since that row in specific fit on the other condition

Comment: @matszwecja I think this can be done through the for loop, but the amount of data is large and it will not be as fast as you want. I think this can be done somehow using the group by function, but I don't know how to set a condition that groups should be separated.

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 I want to have subgroups where the internal difference in column a1 is equal to one. That is, the difference between the first element and the second is 95, so only the first row belongs to the first group.
Then 2 and 3 lines have a difference of 1, so they belong to the second group. The 4th row belongs to the 3rd group, because the difference between the 4th and 3rd row, in the first column, is 202

Comment: Is it possible, that there is 3 menber in that group?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 Yes, each group can have a different number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is sorted by `a1` and that I understood your problem correctly, I think you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

data = [
    [5, 2],
    [100, 23],
    [101, -2],
    [303, 9],
    [304, 4],
    [709, 14],
    [710, 3],
    [711, 3],
    [988, 21]
]
columns = ['a1', 'a2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

@njit
def get_groups(vals):
    counter = 0
    group = []
    for i in range(len(vals)-1):
        if vals[i+1]-vals[i] == 1:
            group.append(counter)
        else:
            group.append(counter)
            counter += 1
    if vals[-1] - vals[-2] == 1: group.append(group[-1])
    else: group.append(counter + 1)
        
    return group  
    
groups = get_groups(df['a1'].values)
assert len(groups) == len(df)

df['group'] = groups
final_ls = df.reset_index().groupby(['group']).agg({'index': list})['index'].to_list()
final_ls

------------------------------------------------------------
[[0], [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8]]
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `njit` decorator from `numba` makes the looping approach efficient.

Answer (score 1):

We are sorting the the Dataframe by "a1" column, then finding the difference of adjacent values. Now we have the difference, we can start grouping.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [5, 2],
    [100, 23],
    [101, -2],
    [303, 9],
    [304, 4],
    [709, 14],
    [710, 3],
    [711, 3],
    [988, 21]
]
columns = ['a1', 'a2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

# To sort the values of "a1" column
df=df.sort_values(by=['a1'])
# To find the difference between the adjacent values
df['difference']=df['a1'].diff()

# Sorted index
indexs=df.index.tolist()

group=[]

# To check the difference, before this row
check=-1
for i,diff in enumerate(df['difference']):
    if diff==0 or diff==1:
        if check==1:
            group[-1].append(indexs[i])
        else:
            group.append([indexs[i-1],indexs[i]])
    check=diff

# For finding indexes that are not in group
z=[]
for x in group: [z.append(w) for w in x]
for t in (set(indexs)-set(z)):
    group.append([t])
print(group)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [0], [8]]
```

Comment: A bit of disadvantage is that, we have to find the indexes that are not in group at last. I am not able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above pushed me to a fairly short and simple code to get an answer. Thank you all very much!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [5, 2],
    [100, 23],
    [101, -2],
    [303, 9],
    [304, 4],
    [709, 14],
    [710, 3],
    [711, 3],
    [988, 21]
]
columns = ['a1', 'a2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)


diff = 1
index_groups = [[df.index[0]]]
for index in df.index[1:]:
    if df.loc[index, 'a1'] - df.loc[index-1, 'a1'] == diff:
        index_groups[-1].append(index)
    else:
        index_groups.append([index])
index_groups
```